# Natural language question answering using BERT from tensorflow not working

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model

Natural language question answering using BERT from tensorflow not working . for every input its giving empty array as result in my project, then I tried tensorflow's deom page, its not working their also

Comment: can you please add code or more info?